# output results coxph with frailty using stargazer

Tags: r, data-visualization, survival

Is there a way to output the results of a cox ph with frailty term using stargazer? I get the following error when I try it:

> stargazer(fit1)
>   Error in .summary.object$coef[, "z"] : subscript out of bounds

Without the frailty term it is possible. Could someone help me out?

Edit: If my question is unclear, I will create an example. However, I can't share my data.

Edit2: Example:

```
library(survival)
library(stargazer)
data(rats)

cox_ph=coxph(Surv(time/52,status)~factor(rx), data=rats)
stargazer(cox_ph)

cox_ph_with_frailty=coxph(Surv(time/52,status)~factor(rx)+frailty(litter), data=rats)
stargazer(cox_ph_with_frailty)
str(cox_ph_with_frailty)
```

stargazer(cox_ph) produces nice Latex output, stargazer(cox_ph_with_frailty) produces the above error.

Comment: can you share an example along with str(fit1)?

Comment: I produced an example. I can add the str(fit1) if it is necessary, however it is quite large.

Comment: I believe that the stargazer does not support 'coxph.penal'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have expertise in coxph models. Howeveer, I went through the structure of the two models and found the class of "cox_ph_with_frailty" to be **coxph.penal**.

end of str(cox_ph)

[image]

end of stargazer(cox_ph_with_frailty)

[image]

I have gone through the [documentation for stargazer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf). It clearly says that it supports  coxph, clogit and survreg.

[image]

I am aware that texreg will be of more use. The [documentation for texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/texreg.pdf) says it supports coxph.penal.

[image]

Another [document by Philip Leifeld](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf) is also confirming this.

[image]

However, When I tried texreg I found that the texreg and extract were not reproducing the complete information available in the output of "cox_ph_with_frailty". We need to do some tweaks in the function.

Comment: I consider this a complete answer. Thanks!